# Print the days of two given dates in groovy

Tags: groovy

```
class Example {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      def date =new Date().format("MM/dd/yy");
      Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
      String date1= scanner.next();
      String date2= scanner.next();
      def duration =(date2-date1)
      return (date2 -date1).days;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You just post a code dump? What happens when you run that code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajesh-kushwaha-dates.

[app/src/main/groovy/rajesh/kushwaha/dates/App.groovy](https://github.com/jeffbrown/rajesh-kushwaha-dates/blob/82961687f3489c67bbaa10ee664673b73ddbf376/app/src/main/groovy/rajesh/kushwaha/dates/App.groovy)

```
package rajesh.kushwaha.dates

class App {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        String format = 'MM/dd/yyyy'

        Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in)

        // Error handling ommited for brevity...

        print "Enter First Date $format: "
        Date date1= Date.parse(format, scanner.next())

        print "Enter Second Date $format: "
        Date date2= Date.parse(format, scanner.next())

        def duration =(date2-date1)

        println "Duration: $duration"
    }
}
```

That appears to work:

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/rajesh-kushwaha-dates.git
Cloning into 'rajesh-kushwaha-dates'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 20, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (20/20), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
remote: Total 20 (delta 0), reused 20 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (20/20), 59.52 KiB | 628.00 KiB/s, done.
~ $ 
~ $ cd rajesh-kushwaha-dates 
rajesh-kushwaha-dates (main)$ 
rajesh-kushwaha-dates (main)$ ./gradlew run -q --console=plain
Enter First Date MM/dd/yyyy: 01/05/2022
Enter Second Date MM/dd/yyyy: 02/26/2022
Duration: 52
```